# How can I change the country to Ukraine in Apple App Store?

Tags: itunes, mac-app-store

I cannot change the country to Ukraine in the app store, how can I do this?

I have heard other people do this but for my client he is stuck with a USA country.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS:

- Open Settings, and go to "iTunes & App Stores"
- Tap on the Apple ID and enter the associated password
- Choose "Country/Region" and select the new country to associate the account with

On Mac/Windows through iTunes:

- Launch iTunes and go to the iTunes Store
- Click on "Account" and log in, under "Apple ID Summary" choose "Change Country or Region"
- Select the new country as desired

Beware that either method will only work if you have an app store balance of `$0.00`. You will also need to update billing to suit the new country.

Answer (score 1):

Sign in to the account for the iTunes Store region you’d like to use. If already signed in to an account, from Settings, choose Store and then View Account.

Tap “Change Country of Region” and follow the on screen process of changing your region. Agree to the terms and conditions for the region if necessary, and then change your billing information.

on the iPhone go into Settings -> iTunes & App Stores -> Apple ID, and then Sign Out. When you Sign in again you’ll be redirected to the new country’s App Store.